# iOS - 50MB file with 1 million entries

Tags: ios, core-data, storage

I have text-delimited file with 1 million entries, e.g.

A;B;C;D;E;F;G......n

I'd like to create an iOS app that will able the user to sort and filter columns.

What is the best way to store this info locally? Will this be too much for iOS to handle?

Would I be better creating a Web service?

Thanks

Comment: use an sqlite database. it'll be far more efficient than having to load/parse that file every time.

Comment: I doubt ios will allow an App enough memory to complete such a task in any timely manner.  It might even end up crashing the app.  Like @Marc said, it would be huge improvment if you replaced text parsing with table querying.

Comment: My suspicions exactly - sharding the way to go?

Comment: If necessary, parse it once at the start, and save the data in a local db, then perform your operations on the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sqlite3. Do proper indexing.

If your data is read-only, performance will be far more manageable. If you're updating the data  very frequently, you may run into performance issues.

Make sure to experiment with different generations of hardware and restrict app to only the ones that can support.

It should be simple enough to experiment. I've had no trouble with database sizes ~8Megs on 2nd genration iphones/iPod touch (~10-20K entries). Latest generation hardware and software should be able to support much more. I'm not sure how much more.

Make sure to experiment and report your findings here.